# How to configure the webpacker to work with stylus so I can use Vuetify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js, vuetify.js, webpacker

I have webpacker working for basic a vue.js/rails app but I would like to configure it so stylus files compile to css so I can use Vuetify. Does anyone know how to do this?
My existing working stand alone vuetify/vue.js app has the following webpack config:

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue'
  }, 
  {
      test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
      loader: 'style!css!sass'
  }
]
},
vue: {
  loaders: {
    scss: 'style!css!sass'
  }
}
```

The syntax for webpacker seems to be a bit different for webpacker. My rails app has /config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.set('styl', {
test: /\.styl$/,
use: 'stylus-loader'
}),
environment.loaders.set('styl', {
test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
use: 'style!css!sass'
})
module.exports = environment
```

But I am getting this error:
**Undefined variable: "$chip-label-color".in /rails_project_path/node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css (line 6, column 134917)**

Does anyone have an example of how to configure Vuetify with Rails Webapcker?

Comment: I'm just hitting the same error about $chip-label-color ... and that is the only time $foo syntax is used in the Vuetify dist css. So I'm thinking that it is a bug in their generating a dist files.

For now, I've just replaced the $chip-label-color with a CSS color (ie: pink).

Comment: Just wondering, what makes you believe this is stylus related?

Comment: bug was reported and fixed https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2623

Answer (score 3):

With webpacker 3 you can add loaders as explained in the [loaders](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md) section of the docs.

Here is my configuration for stylus-loader in my webpack/environment.js

```
environment.loaders.append('stylus', {
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
})
```

Also additional information can be found here on vuetify's website: [setting up stylus loader with webpack](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme) and [here](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader)

Also, I don't think environment.loaders.set works anymore. Use append.

Comment: I've put `postcss-loader` to have postcss treatment after stylus pre-processing. And use `'vue-style-loader` in place of style-loader as [vue-loader doc say](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#stylus). For the test, I have to use `\.styl(us)?$` to have loader parse <style lang="stylus"> tags. So :`{
    test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
    use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'stylus-loader']
}`